# Play questions using ffmpeg or ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to play media with command command via ffmpeg or ffplay?

```
implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5'
implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaPlayer:1.0.4'
```

- This library is currently in use.

Comment: what kind of media are you talking about here?

Comment: I want to play video images using ffmpeg. I have implemented it up to play with the library mentioned above, but I would like to give it more advanced options but it is not supported.
For example, you want functions such as double speed playback or video cropping.